# combobox.text += "sometext" dropdown

Tags: text, combobox, addition

I want to choose from a drop-down list box, and add it in the combobox.text example "one;two;three"
how can I do it???
this code does not work because of the updates(((

```
FI_ComboBox[ii].SelectionChangeCommitted += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                {

                    ComboBox FI_ComboBox1 = (ComboBox)sender;
                    FI_ComboBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {

                            FI_ComboBox1.Text += FI_ComboBox1.Items[FI_ComboBox1.SelectedIndex]+";";
                        }
                        ));

                };
```